# Pandas import sometimes fails

Tags: python, pandas, windows, conda

I'm running hundreds of parallel Python jobs on several Windows servers (using HTCondor for job distribution). I have set up a Conda environment on a network path - this environment has pandas installed. I have confirmed that the pandas install is working as expected, by activating the environment and testing that the import works.

However, out of several hundred jobs being launched, a handful of them fail with strange import errors. For example:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.arrays.datetimes'
```

Or

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.dtypes.dtypes'
```

Am I dealing with bizarre network behaviour here, or is there something wrong with my environment?

Comment: can you pin point the failures to 1 windows server? a certain error is coming from the same windows server that had succeeded other task?

Comment: I'd try logging the value from `pd.__path__` (assuming `import pandas as pd`). My guess is some of the servers have packages from another system- or user-level Python leaking into the environment, and this leads to loading a different version of Pandas that lacks the specific modules being requested.